# Iterated Integral question and Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { (3) Let } f \text { be an integrable function. Express the integral }} \\ {\qquad \int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{2 y} \int_{0}^{x+y} f(x, y, z)\, d z\, d x \,d y} \\ {\text { as a sum of iterated integrals in the order } d x d y d z \text { . }}\end{array}
$$

For this to be in order $dx\, dy\, dz$, we  need $f$ to be a continuous function and partial derivative need to exist but no condition is given as such so how to tackle such kind of function?

Comment: No? If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (or $L^1([0,1]\times [0,2]\times [0,3])$ as seems to be your case), then the interchangability of integration order is part of the Fubini theorem.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou so what should be answer can you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is  $\int_0^{3}\int_0^{1} \int_{\max \{z-y,y\}}^{2y} f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$. Justification is by Fubini's Theoorem. [ Note that the inequalities $0<z<x+y, y<x<2y, 0<y<1$ are equivalent to the inequalities $\max \{z-y,y\} <x <2y, 0<y<1$ and $0<z<3$].

Comment: Isn't it the case that x range from 0 to 2

Comment: $x$ can on;y go up to $2y$. Of course, $2y <2$ but the limit of integration w.r..t $x$ has to go up to $2y$ not $2$.  @mathsstudent

Comment: Then for z why the limit of integration from 0 to 3?

Comment: @mathsstudent Once you have taken care of all the restrictions on $x$ and $y$ you have to integrate w.r.t. $z$ from its minimum value to its maximum value. [No other variable can  appear in the final integral]. The maximum value of $z$ is $3$ because the maximum value of $y$ is $2$ and the maximum value of $x$ is $1$.